# Post request failed in android application

Tags: android

I’m trying to do a login system for my application. The problem that when I add a Bundle to set information for my fragment, the request respond show that the account doesn’t exist, on the other side the log display me the right account information, wath mean that the request it's well done, but i don't why the `onPostExecute` show me the false response. **Here is the example**

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
        //LoginTask = null;
        //showProgress(false);
        if (success) {
            finish();
        } else {
            //password.setError(getString(R.string.error_incorrect_password));
            //password.requestFocus();
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            builder.setTitle("Error !");
            builder.setMessage("The information entered is incorrect.\nPlease try again!")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();

        }

    }
```

**My DoInBackground Function :**

```
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO: attempt authentication against a network service.

        try {
            // Simulate network access.
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return false;
        }

        ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", mEmail));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", mPassword));

        //Prepare the Post query

        try {
            HttpClient clientHttp = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = clientHttp.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream is = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = reader.readLine();
            sb.append(line + "\n");
            is.close();

            String result = sb.toString();
            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(result);

            //Affichage de test
            System.out.println(jObj);

            if(jObj.isNull("false")){

                //Créer un Bundle pour déposer les infos
                infos = new Bundle();
                infos.putString("ID",jObj.getString("ID"));
                infos.putString("Name",jObj.getString("display_name"));
                infos.putString("ImgUrl","http://unchained-network.com/uploads/profilpics/53f5c570b6ac2.png");


                Fragment fg = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frgmnt);
                //Charger les infos dans l'activité
                fg.setArguments(infos);

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), HomesActivity.class);
                //Lançer l'activité
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);

            }

        }catch (Exception e){

            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

**The log response :**

```
09-19 10:00:48.139    2326-2346/com.example.user.unchained I/System.out﹕  {"ID":"50","filename":"5379aae5ef60a.jpeg","display_name":"karim ennassiri"}
```

***Error Log :***

```
09-19 11:10:16.227    2452-2452/com.example.user.unchained E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.user.unchained, PID: 2452
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.user.unchained.EmailLoginActivity$LoginTask.onPostExecute(EmailLoginActivity.java:314)
        at com.example.user.unchained.EmailLoginActivity$LoginTask.onPostExecute(EmailLoginActivity.java:239)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrong piece of coding.

The whole below thing should go in onPostExecute. This is ui coding should not do in background. Try moving this

```
Fragment fg = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frgmnt);
            //Charger les infos dans l'activité
            fg.setArguments(infos);

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), HomesActivity.class);
            //Lançer l'activité
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
```

Comment: the app crashed when i moved it into the onPostExecute function :/

Comment: Thats means your app is crashing doInBackgroud as well. And ur getting false value returned. try putting logs in catch block

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is on `finish()` called in the `onPostExecute()`; seems you want to finish an activity form an `AsyncTask`.

the better way is to manage an `Handler` by `onPostExecute` of the `AsyncTask`, managed by UIThread or by the `Activity` you want to finish, in that case when triggered you can close the activity by itself

Comment: my whole probleme that i've added the bundle without it all thigs is right

Comment: I saw Bundle args filled in right way, I don't know if in the Fragment they are collected, but the Log you attached is definitely clear, a null pointer exception is risen onPostExecute(EmailLoginActivity.java:239) and that means is not related to the bundle missing agrgs or whatever; BTW is not correct to manage UI Application components in an AsyncTask, so you cannot manage activities or ListView or whatever in a parallel task as AsyncTask that want to manage Application Components in the UI Thread.

Answer (score 0):

In the Main Activity you should:

```
/*
* Declared in the Activity
*/    

private AsyncHandler mAsyncHandler;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    ...
    ...
    mAsyncHandler = new AsyncHandler();
}
```

And declaring an Handler as shown below:

```
    public class AsyncHandler extends Handler {
    public static final int BUILD_RESPONSE = 10;
    public static final int FALSE_RESPONSE = 100;
    public static final int TRUE_RESPONSE = 1000;

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        stopWaitingProgress();

        switch (msg.what) {
            case BUILD_RESPONSE:
                //Créer un Bundle pour déposer les infos
                infos = new Bundle();
                infos.putString("ID",jObj.getString("ID"));
                infos.putString("Name",jObj.getString("display_name"));
                infos.putString("ImgUrl","http://unchained-network.com/uploads/profilpics/53f5c570b6ac2.png");


                Fragment fg = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frgmnt);
                //Charger les infos dans l'activité
                fg.setArguments(infos);

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), HomesActivity.class);
                //Lançer l'activité
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);

                break;

            case FALSE_RESPONSE:

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                builder.setTitle("Error !");
                builder.setMessage("The information entered is incorrect.\nPlease try again!")
                  .setCancelable(false)
                  .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
                break;


            case TRUE_RESPONSE:
                finish();      <<---  Supposing you have the context for this one
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

For the class manage the AsyncTask you should:

```
    /*
* Declaring a field as AsyncHandler in the class implementing AsyncTask (see below))
*/    
private AsyncHandler mAsyncConnectionHandler;

/*
* ... and whern from the Activity instantiate the AsyncTask, pass the Acitvity
* mAsyncHandler to the AsyncTask mAsyncConnectionHandler field    
*/   


protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
    // TODO: attempt authentication against a network service.

    try {
        // Simulate network access.
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        return false;
    }

    ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", mEmail));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", mPassword));

    //Prepare the Post query

    try {
        HttpClient clientHttp = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = clientHttp.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream is = entity.getContent();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = reader.readLine();
        sb.append(line + "\n");
        is.close();

        String result = sb.toString();
        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(result);

        //Affichage de test
        System.out.println(jObj);

        if(jObj.isNull("false")){
            Message msg = Message.obtain(mAsyncConnectionHandler, AsyncHandler.BUILD_RESPONSE);
            mAsyncConnectionHandler.sendMessage(msg);
        }

    }catch (Exception e){

        return false;
    }

    return true;
}


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {

    if (success) {

        Message msg = Message.obtain(mAsyncConnectionHandler, AsyncHandler.TRUE_RESPONSE);
        mAsyncConnectionHandler.sendMessage(msg);
    } else {
        Message msg = Message.obtain(mAsyncConnectionHandler, AsyncHandler.FALSE_RESPONSE);
        mAsyncConnectionHandler.sendMessage(msg);
    }

}
```